# Windows 7 - making Bootable DVD

Tags: windows-7, dvd, bootable-media

i have downloaded an ISO file that is around 3.36 GB in size. I am running Windows 7 so i used built in burn option to burn the ISO. Now i restarted my system and changed the boot options and selected DVD as first boot option. But my system does not recognize the dvd as bootable device. Any possible reasons?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you burn the *image as an image* or burn the image as a *file*? You should not be seeing the image file itself when you double-click.